# Extracting text from Push Notification using Parse.com

Tags: android, text, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a receiver to extract the text from the push notification powered by Parse.com, I receive the notification but it looks like my BroadcastReceiver isn't called, as the Log.d isn't logging

my MainActivity.java onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Parse.initialize(this, "-", "-"); //removed keys for question
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());   
}
```

my Manifest.xml receivers

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver.MyCustomReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

my BroadcastReceiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString(
                "com.parse.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel
                + " with:");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

my package is

```
package com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver;
```

Thank you,

SOLUTION:

got it working, the idea was in the json object being sen it self, template {"action": "com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver.UPDATE_STATUS",
                                   "name": "Vaughn",
                                   "newsItem": "Man bites dog"}

Comment: you probably shouldn't post your personal PARSE_APPLICATION_ID and PARSE_CLIENT_KEY in your question...

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie it's ok it's a test application anyway, but I removed them, thank you, any solution? thx

Comment: I have never used it but I am reading the documentation.

Comment: got it working, the idea was in the json object being sen it self, template {"action": "com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver.UPDATE_STATUS",
                                   "name": "Vaughn",
                                   "newsItem": "Man bites dog"}

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

got it working, the idea was in the json object being sen it self, template {"action": "com.example.parsepushnotificationreceiver.UPDATE_STATUS", "name": "Vaughn", "newsItem": "Man bites dog"}